# Azure B2C tenant deployment fails in Europe. Why?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-bicep, azure-ad-b2c

I have this bicep file that deploys an Azure B2C tenant in `location: 'Australia'`

```
resource b2cDirectory 'Microsoft.AzureActiveDirectory/b2cDirectories@2021-04-01' = {
    location: 'Australia'
    name: 'tenantname1.onmicrosoft.com'
    sku: {
      name: 'PremiumP2'
      tier: 'A0'
    }
    properties: {
      createTenantProperties: {
        countryCode: 'AU'
        displayName: 'tenantname1 B1Cd223'
      }
    }
    tags: {
      Department: 'Dev'
    }
  }
```

This works fine. but it doesn't work for  `location: 'Europe'` even though they say they support it.

[image]

This is the error I'm getting when I try to deploy this in `location: 'Europe'`.

[image]

Is this a temporary thing or am I missing something?

Comment: Would suggest to refer this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.azureactivedirectory/b2cdirectories?pivots=deployment-language-bicep review the resource format section (add the following bicep to your template) and verify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

Initially, I got same error in my environment.

> {"status":"Failed","error":{"code":"Deployment Failed", "message":"Atleast one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"InternalSer verError", "message":"{\r\n"error"; {\r\n" "code":
> "ResourceDeploymentFailure",\r\n"message": "The response for resou rce had empty or invalid content."\r\n }\r\n}"}]}}_

I tried with some changes in bicep code as below :

**`test.bicep:`**

```
resource b2cDirectory 'Microsoft.AzureActiveDirectory/b2cDirectories@2021-04-01' = {
    location: 'europe'
    name: 'demotenant326.onmicrosoft.com'
    sku: {
      name: 'Standard'
      tier: 'A0'
    }
    properties: {
      createTenantProperties: {
        countryCode: 'DE'
        displayName: 'demo1tenantv B1Cd223'
      }
    }
    tags: {
      Department: 'pro'
    }
  }
```

In the above bicep file I changed **`sku`**, **`country code`** = '**`DE'`** indicates **`Germany`**and it deploys an Azure B2C tenant with `location: 'europe'` successfully.

**Console:**
[image]

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -TemplateFile test.bicep -ResourceGroupName <your resource grp>
WARNING: /home/venkatesan/test.bicep(2,15) : Warning no-hardcoded-location: A resource location should not use a hard-coded string or variable value. Please use a parameter value, an expression, or the string 'global'. Found: 'europe' [https://aka.ms/bicep/linter/no-hardcoded-location]

DeploymentName          : test
ResourceGroupName       : <your resource grp>
ProvisioningState       : Succeeded
Timestamp               : 2/17/2023 8:08:56 AM
Mode                    : Incremental
TemplateLink            : 
Parameters              : 
Outputs                 : 
DeploymentDebugLogLevel :
```

**Reference:**
[Region availability and data residency - Azure AD B2C | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/data-residency)